# Dynamic select statement with join and with union

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to prepare a dynamic `select with join` and `select with union` statment using the stored procedure. For which I have 
the following data.

I have two tables:

**Table**: Test1

```
select * from test1;
a   b
------
A   B
C   D
E   F
```

**Table**: Test1

```
select * from test2;
a   b
------
A   B
C   D
```

**Note**: Now I want to apply `Joins` and `Union` to these tables(THERE MIGHT BE MORE TABLES ALSO) at one at a time using
stored procedure. I have created demo stored procedure as shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Pro_Test
@Columns VARCHAR(100), --Columns to display
@Tables VARCHAR(1000), --Two or More tables names may pass here
@JoinORUnion VARCHAR(50), --Join or Union the tables
@IfJoinOnColumn VARCHAR(50) ---If join has pass then ON which column

AS

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) 

    IF @JoinORUnion = 'Inner Join'
    BEGIN

        SET @query = '';    ---Here want to prepare select with join statement

        EXEC(@query);

    END

    ELSE IF @JoinORUnion = 'Union all'
    BEGIN

        SET @query = '';    ---Here want to prepare select with union statement

        EXEC(@query);

    END

GO
```

If I pass:

```
EXECUTE Pro_Test
@Columns        = 'a,b',
@Tables         = 'Test1,Test2',
@JoinORUnion    = 'Inner Join',
@IfJoinOnColumn = 'a';
```

Then the statement should be looks like:

```
select test1.a,test1.b from test1
INNER JOIN 
test2 ON test1.a = test2.a;
```

Result:

```
a   b
------
A   B
C   D
```

If I pass:

```
EXECUTE Pro_Test
@Columns        = 'a,b',
@Tables         = 'Test1,Test2',
@JoinORUnion    = 'Union all',
@IfJoinOnColumn = '';
```

Then the statement should be looks like:

```
select a,b from test1
union all
select a,b from test2
```

Result:

```
a   b
------
A   B
C   D
E   F
A   B
C   D
```

Comment: and? where is your problem?

Comment: I would say that this is the bad approach and will subject to sql injection

Comment: is this your requirement @mak

Comment: @mohan111, Yes! this is requirement.

Comment: @Madhivanan, Then what would be the better approach?

Comment: why go for dynamic that you can achieve in simple if conditions and performance wise also nothing much of difference

Comment: @mohan111, The problem is the dynamic number of tables passed as a parameter to the stored procedure and according to that statement has to change.